# What is the private beta ?

Tags: discussion

There is a silver badge [Beta](https://askubuntu.com/badges/30/beta), it says Actively participated in the private beta.

What is the private beta?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ask Ubuntu once started off as a simple proposal on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716). During which people helped to shape and define the parameters which the site would operate under. Once this was defined the proposal went through a commitment phase to see how much traction it would gain and test how many people were interested in this idea. After that [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/sites) launched https://askubuntu.com/ - a private beta to see if the site could survive a public beta launch. As you can imagine it then launched into public beta where anyone could join and shortly after public beta became the site you see today; full launched as Ask Ubuntu.

You can check out each part of the phase, from definition to launch on the Area 51 profile.

Comment: Ohh I see, Thanks for your help.

Comment: And for more info, see http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq