# Private Beta Participation

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the private beta ?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1394/what-is-the-private-beta)

How do you enrol for the ask ubuntu private beta? There is a badge for it. I would like to see it in action. Perhaps I would be able to give feedback.